# How do I declare variables contained in an 'included' layout?

Tags: android-layout

My primary and secondary layout contain variables. I included the secondary layout in the primary. How do I access and declare the variables in the secondary layout in my MainActivity since the secondary is a customized xml?

I found it difficult comprehending the dynamics of data binding.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="#75c49b">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView15"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:src="@drawable/pp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/changePhoto"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView5"
            android:text="Change Photo"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView15"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="57dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView5"
            android:text="User ID:"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView16"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView15"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView15"
            android:layout_below="@+id/logOut"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="Welcome"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="18dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/getFirstName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView16"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView16"
            android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="9dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView16"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView16"
            android:text="Baba"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="18dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/logOut"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
            android:text="Logout"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />


    </RelativeLayout>


    <ScrollView

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="false"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:scrollingCache="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include layout="@layout/themenugrid"> </include>
```

I want to access the variables in my customized .xml file (themenugrid) since I have included them in the primary layout.

Comment: All included layout becomes part of the parent layout. you can access by findViewBy Id() method

Comment: Thank you so much. It was really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just access it like how you will access any other element in your xml.
Here in your case, write:

```
 TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.sample_text_view);
 textView.setText("Sample 2");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly access the `Id` of include layout using the `findViewById` in .xml file. because include layout is a part of the parent layout. no need to do extra code or anything.

Check below example.

```
TextView tvName = findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
tvName.setText("Your Include layout ID access and set Text in this textView");
```

Comment: Thank you so much Kaushal. I'm fine now.

Answer (score 0):

do like

**themenugrid.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sample_text_view"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World Sample"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Parent layout xml where you include**

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/header_layout"
    layout="@layout/themenugrid"
    />
```

**In java file**

```
 View header = findViewById(R.id.header_layout);
 TextView textView = header.findViewById(R.id.sample_text_view);
 textView.setText("Sample 2");
```

Answer (score 0):

All included layout becomes part of the parent layout. you can access by findViewBy Id(). ie

```
 View textView = findViewById(R.id.id_inclued_view);
 textView.setText("My Name is Khan. And I am not terrorist :P");
```